# java native JSON api for parsing

Tags: java, json

I've following JSON structure coming in,

```
{
  "name": "product new",
  "brand": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

I can extract

```
jsonObject = Json.createReader(httpServletRequest.getInputStream()).readObject();
jsonObject.getString("name")
```

Errors:

```
jsonObject.getInt("brand.id")
jsonObject.getInt("category.id")
```

I'm using Java API for JSON.

**Edit** If I access

```
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("brand"));
// response {"id":1}

System.out.println(jsonObject.get("brand.id"));
// null
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: `jsonObject.getInt("brand.id")` is not an error. What's your actual error message?

Comment: it's coming as null

Comment: What did you see in the documentation to support your syntax? Why don't you use `getJsonObject("brand").getInt("id")`?

Comment: ok, that worked, see my edits just in case please

Comment: In case of what?

Comment: is there a way that `brand.id` could work, otherwise you may post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the API you're using supports nested expressions. You'll need to access the parent object, and then the specific field:

```
System.out.println(jsonObject.getJsonObject("brand").getInt("id"));
```

Or you can use an API that accepts a path expression, like [Jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#at(java.lang.String)):

```
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(httpServletRequest.getInputStream());
System.out.println(node.at("/brand/id").asInt());
```